# Permalink Goes to Old Page

Tags: wordpress

I have been working on a site created by another developer. I have been fixing the site to make it more visually appealing. I am also responsible for adding new events and pictures which i self taught myself to do.

I have a situation where I have a page with the following permalink:

http://www.cic-nj.org/events/

The problem is that this link goes to a page that does not show the edits that i am making under that page and there is no other page listed that shows the info it actually displays.

this is what I have in the editor box on wordpress that I want it to show.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yJQU.png)

this is what appears when url is used or when i click view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weLPX.png)

I have been sure to click update and renewing page to view it. it's like its going to a ghost page i can not edit.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing "slug collision": more than one thing in your WP install has the same slug.

The problem that you have is `events` is a custom post type, with a slug set to `events` - therefore the url http://www.cic-nj.org/events/ is directing to the listing of events.  This is an automatic feature of WordPress.  (Note - you can see more details to support this conclusion by the fact that you've got individual events accessible at url's such as http://www.cic-nj.org/events/blue-apron-info-session/ )

Note that custom post type slugs will always take priority over a page / post slug.

You have a couple of options:

1. If you want a page to display the content that you've created, the page's slug / permalink must be different than `events`
2. If it's acceptable, you can rename the slug of the "events" custom post type to something different.  This has the potential consequence of losing SEO "juice".
3. If it's acceptable, you can remove the custom post type, if you aren't going to use them any longer.

NOTE: It may be tempting to ask "how do I remove the custom post type", or "how do I change the post type slug".  Those are **different questions**, and if you need to ask, they should be asked in a different question - not added as a comment below.